# transition with same start/end in UML state diagram

Tags: uml, state, diagram, fsm

I am new to UML,
regrading FSM diagram, how to represent two transitions that lead to same state, 
for example, I'm in state1:

```
when(event1)-->action1-->state2
when(event2)-->action2-->state2
```

I mean do I need to draw two lines from state1 to state2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to draw two lines since the event and action is part of the line.

as you can see in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:UML_state_machine_Fig1.png

your line will get a text like `"event1 / action1"` and `"event2 / action2"`.

If you don't generate code from your diagram, you can also use one line and add a text like `"event1 / action1 OR event2 / action2"` if this is more readable.

I consider UML as a guide - sometimes you have to change the rules a little bit in order to create something readable and useful. :-)

Comment: (+1) @Ralf. The answer is good. But, I would give an extra (+1) for "UML as a Guide". For example, In Activity charts, I make a different decision node for: (a) Many incoming arrows, one outcoming arrow, (b) Single incoming arrow, many outcoming arrows. Even if UML allows to have many-to-many. And I fill gray (b).